# error during the import of the files for MaaS with its stable release via ppa

Tags: maas

after I've added the stable release of Maas via ppa on my Ubuntu 14.04lts Svr and made the upgrade, during the import of its images file using the command:

```
$: sudo maas-import-pxe-files
```

I've received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-import-pxe-files", line 18, in <module>
    from provisioningserver.import_images.boot_resources import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 35, in <module>
    from provisioningserver.boot import BootMethodRegistry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from provisioningserver.kernel_opts import compose_kernel_command_line
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/kernel_opts.py", line 24, in <module>
    from provisioningserver.driver import ArchitectureRegistry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/driver/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from provisioningserver.utils.registry import Registry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/utils/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from crochet import run_in_reactor
ImportError: No module named crochet
```

while, without to make the upgrade it works perfectly.
its there someone who had the same my problem and resolved it?

thanks in advance for support and for any other suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing the dependency - python-crochet. Had similar problem and it was solved by doing this. More on the solution can be found on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas/+bug/1311765.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time write an answer. While providing a link containing the solution is ok, it would be nice if you could copy and add the essential parts to your answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. When I'll have a few time I want to  re-try to upgrade MaaS via ppa stable and I'll inform you after to use your solution.